# Update all values of a Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary with this structure

```
var profiles: Dictionary<String, Bool> = ["open": true, "encrypted": false, "sound":true, "picture":false]
```

I want to create a function that reset all the dictionary values to true. Is there a short method to do that or shall I loop through it and change the values one by one?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a struct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Easy one-liner for you:

```
profiles.keys.forEach { profiles[$0] = true }
```

This iterates through every key in the dictionary and sets the value for that key to `true`.  `$0` represents the first argument in the `forEach` closure (the key).  I don't see a way to change all of the values to a single value without looping.

Comment: Or `for key in profiles.keys { profiles[key] = false }` – only slightly longer, but easier to read :)

Comment: @MartinR it also avoids creating a closure, which may have performance benefits

Comment: Reading you answer, at first I thought mutating the dictionary which didn't seem right. It's nice trick that you're doing. I just wish there an easy mutating function. Is there any reason to that?

Comment: @Honey re your edit: is `$0.key` required with Swift 4 now?  Previously you could do `$0` for key and `$1` for value, or `$0.0` for key and `$0.1` for value (syntax not interchangeable).

Comment: @Honey as for mutating the dictionary, there is this [`updateValue(_:forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/1539001-updatevalue) which you might be able to take advantage of

Comment: @Honey we're looping the keys, so there's no `$0.key`, but `$0` and `$1`.

Comment: Thank you for fixing @LinusGeffarth.

Answer (score 3):

```
dictionary.forEach({ (key, value) -> Void in 
    dictionary[key] = true                 
})
```

And here another approach. In this case only update these dictionary entries which must be updated..

```
dictionary.filter({ $0.value == false })
    .forEach({ (key, _) -> Void in 
              dictionary[key] = true               
})
```

Comment: won't this produce a warning for the unused `value` parameter?

Comment: You don't need to use `enumerated()` here. Also there's no need for `filter` and `forEach` – a simple `for in` loop can do both in one go – `for (key, value) in profiles where !value { profiles[key] = true }`.

Comment: You're right @Hamish. My second snippet it's only an "exercise" :) It's preferable a more readable solution, ;)

Comment: That filter is way overcomplicating this task.  The time complexity of that is already more that just iterating through the entire key list in one shot.  If you really wanted to only update the values that weren't already `true`, just use `forEach` and check if the value for the specified key is not false, and update it.

Comment: In a 4 key/value dictionary sure ;) @JAL

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this particular cat…

```
profiles.forEach { profiles[$0.0] = true }
```